# Importing an enum that is nested within another class from a different package(Java)

Tags: java, enums

How to pass the value of an enum declared within another class to a method of that class?

In my other class which is in a different package from where the enum is defined, I have declared the enum as:

```
public static enum Status
{
  SUCCESS, FAILURE;
}
```

I've tried to import the Enum using import static as follows:

```
import static com.org.xx.yy.classname.Status

and

import com.org.xx.yy.classname.Status;
```

With both the cases in my test program, I am able to compile but I am getting a run time error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.org.xx.yy.classname$Status
```

Comment: no need to use static import just use `import com.org.xx.yy.classname.Status;` Also you should be getting compile errors, not runtime errors..

Comment: Well.. I tried both the cases and I still get the same run time error that the class is not found. I am not sure why it is treating the enum as a class.

Comment: Because enums ARE classes. They're just a particular kind of class. One that extends the `Enum` class, and can only have hard-coded instances, instantiated within the class itself. But still classes.

Comment: And if you're getting a runtime NoClassDefFoundError, then you probably just need to recompile the package/class that contains the enum. Other than that, it might be a versioning problem.

Comment: For some reason your class is not in the classpath or your modules are not configured correctly. Your code is fine if it compiles. This is a *runtime* exception after all. As others said, you must make sure your class containing the enum is build correctly and that the rebuild package replaces the old one. That may mean *cleaning* the projects.

Comment: Do you know what causes a `NoClassDefFoundError`? Did you read the _javadoc_ of that class? Basically it means your compile-time classpath (or module-path, I don't know because I couldn't see what java version you are using) is different to your runtime classpath (or module-path). How are you compiling your java code and how are you running it?

Comment: @Abra running javadoc NoClassDefFoundError or javadoc java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError  throws this error: 

javadoc: warning - No source files for package NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: What java version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't getting a compile error for missing that class but you *are* getting the runtime `NoClassDefFoundError` then that means you must have linked against that class at compile time, without actually compiling it into your executable code, then you run your code without that class on the classpath so it can't find it.

Make sure that your build path is setup correctly to compile that class and try re-building your project OR, if that should be an external class, then add it to your classpath at runtime.

This compiles for me and prints out `"SUCCESS"`

**Main.java**

```
package com.xx.yy.Main;
import com.aa.bb.OtherClass.Status; // <-- Other class in other package

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Status.SUCCESS.name());
    }
}
```

**OtherClass.java**

```
package com.aa.bb;

public class OtherClass {
    public static enum Status {
        SUCCESS, FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

enum and nested enum - package local, final and static. No need to set **static** enum. import *com.org.xx.yy.classname.Status* should work.